# Trigger building the Github's webhook head_commit in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, github

I have configured a Jenkins Pipeline that correctly receives webhooks push notifications from GitHub, on `push` events.
The authentication is done through a deployment key.

Jenkins configuration seems to rely a lot on the concepts of branches and pull requests.
Given my workflow, which consists mostly of creating branches for any needs, and merge changes back onto `master` once things would look fine on the CI, I do not really care about seeing my builds categorized by branch or PR.
I would prefer to see builds based on commits' hashes. I do not see the need to tell Jenkins what branch I want it to match.

My current configuration is not selecting the commit revision I desire. I do not understand how it decides which branch or commit to build, once it receives a push notification. In Jenkins I have set the branch to `**`.

Checking the webhook payload, I noticed that it contains both the list of commits but also something called `head_commit`, with its `id` property being the commit's hash I want to see being built.

I would like Jenkins to do the following:

1. Check what's the head commit in the webhook notification (`head_commit.id` in the payload)
2. Build that precise commit, no matter the branch it is part of
3. Setting a green tick or a red cross beside the commit's hash on Github

Is this possible?